# in bash language, how can i define a list of paths of files?

Tags: bash

In bash language, how can I define a list of paths?

I need something like below:

`list_of_paths = ["$Home/MyDir/test.c", "$Home/YourDir/file.c"]`

Answer (score 2):

An array my be created in `bash` using

```
mypaths=( "/my/first/path" "/my/second/path" )
```

Elements of the array may also be assigned individually:

```
mypaths[0]="/my/first/path"
mypaths[1]="/my/second/path"
```

Note that there should be no spaces around the `=`.

This is described in the section called "Arrays" in the `bash` manual.

Using the array:

```
printf 'The 1st path is %s\n' "${mypaths[0]}"
printf 'The 2nd path is %s\n' "${mypaths[1]}"

for thepath in "${mypaths[@]}"; do
    # use "$thepath" here
done
```

---

Alternative for `/bin/sh` (will also work in `bash` and in a number of other `sh`-like shells):

```
set -- "/my/first/path" "/my/second/path"

printf 'The 1st path is %s\n' "$1"
printf 'The 2nd path is %s\n' "$2"

for thepath do
    # use "$thepath" here
done
```

This uses the only array there is in a `/bin/sh` shell, which is the list of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc., or collectively `$@`).  This list usually contains the command line arguments for the script or shell function, but can be set explicitly in a script with `set`.

The loop at the end may also be written

```
for thepath in "$@"; do
    # use "$thepath" here
done
```

Note that the quoting of every single variable expansion is significant.